# Why is the output of the "$(())" command 0?

Tags: bash, command-line, command

I used the `$(())` command and I seen this error:

```
bash: 0: command not found
```

Why did this error occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$(( ))` is an arithmetic substitution or arithmetic expansion.  Within it, you may do (integer) arithmetic operations, and the shell would carry them out and replace the whole expression with the result of those operations.

You often see it used like in

```bsh
count=$(( count + 1 ))
```

Since there is nothing for the shell to do here (the arithmetic substitution is empty), your `bash` shell decides that the result is zero.

You are using this as a command, which means the shell would try to run the result, `0`, as a command.

It fails, and tells you why ("0: command not found").

---

This, an empty arithmetic substitution, seems to be a corner case that is treated differently in different shells.  The `bash` shell, along with `zsh` and `pdksh` (`ksh` on OpenBSD) tries to execute `0`, while `dash` and `yash` complains:

```
$ dash -c '$(( ))'
dash: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: " "
$ yash -c '$(( ))'
yash: arithmetic: a value is missing
```

The [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) says

> As an extension, the shell may recognize arithmetic expressions beyond those listed.

... which may be what `bash`, `zsh` and `pdksh` does (i.e., they recognize an empty expression as "zero").